# Combine two log and calculate the timestamp gap

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

Is it possible to combine two log which has same related_id and both also has a timestamp field and  compute time gap between their timestamp, right now I has extracted them and give them two label to mark their time and related_id low below format.
So the purpose just to compute the lantency of this request

```
2023-07-19 00:00:00 request related_id 123
2023-07-19 00:00:05 response related_id 123
```

I want these two log can be combine into one

```
relate_id 123 latency 5s
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your logs are properly parsed with promtail and have label set of `related_id` and `type` (for "request" or "response").

You can use query

```
last_over_time(timestamp({type="response"}) [1d:]) - on(related_id) last_over_time(timestamp({type="request"}) [1d:])
```

If it is guaranteed that between request and response never passes more than 5 minutes, this query can be simplified to

```
timestamp({type="response"}) - on(related_id) timestamp({type="request"})
```